# How to make this php-if-statemeent shorter and more redeable?

Tags: php, if-statement, code-generation

I think I'm repeating too much in the following if-statement:

```
<?php $current_language = get_bloginfo( 'language' ); ?>
<div id="next">
    <?php if ( $current_language == 'es-ES' ) : ?>
        <?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Proyecto Siguiente ' . _x( '', 'next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' ); ?>
    <?php elseif ( $current_language == 'zh-TW' ) : ?>
        <?php next_post_link( '%link', '下一個項目 ' . _x( '', 'next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' ); ?>
    <?php elseif ( $current_language == 'zh-CN' ) : ?>
        <?php next_post_link( '%link', '下一个项目 ' . _x( '', 'next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' ); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Project ' . _x( '', 'next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div id="prev">
    <?php if ( $current_language == 'es-ES' ) : ?>
        <?php previous_post_link( '%link', '' . _x( '', 'previous post link', 'twentyten' ) . ' Proyecto Anterior' ); ?>
    <?php elseif ( $current_language == 'zh-TW' ) : ?>
        <?php previous_post_link( '%link', '' . _x( '', 'previous post link', 'twentyten' ) . ' 上一個項目' ); ?>
    <?php elseif ( $current_language == 'zh-CN' ) : ?>
        <?php previous_post_link( '%link', '' . _x( '', 'previous post link', 'twentyten' ) . ' 上一个项目' ); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php previous_post_link( '%link', '' . _x( '', 'previous post link', 'twentyten' ) . ' Previous Project' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

(The repetition of php tags is a WordPress convention I think).

I wonder if there's a way of not repeating the **previous_post_link** and **next_post_link** functions?

Comment: I don't think it is a matter of convention for using php tags unnecessarily, rather convenience. so easily a programmer can copy paste the code without have to open and close tags. the copy paste generation (;

Comment: Yes, it looked like Wordpress right away. It's not a convention and you don't have to repeat tags. So I'd simply lose redundant tags, and use an array, as suggested in below answers. It should result in much cleaner code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one thing is that you don't have to wrap every line in `<?php ... ?>` tags. And since you're repeating the same thing quite a lot, you could use an array instead:

```
<div id="next">
<?php 
$current_language = get_bloginfo( 'language' ); 
$translations = array( 
    'es-ES' => 'Proyecto Siguiente',
    'zh-TW' => '下一個項目',
    'zh-CN' => '下一个项目',
    'en-GB' => 'Next Project'
);

if( !isset( $translations[ $current_language ] ) ) {
    $current_language = 'en-GB';
}

next_post_link( '%link', $translations[ $current_language ].' ' . _x( '', 'next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' ); 
?>
```

If you're translating every string in your app like this, it might be worth considering a more general system behind it like [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php).

Comment: I'm using gettext but I didn't know how to apply that to those functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use switch case as below

```
<?php $current_language = get_bloginfo( 'language' ); ?>
<div id="next">
<?php 
switch($current_language){
     case 'es-ES':
         next_post_link( '%link', 'Proyecto Siguiente ' . _x( '', 'next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' );    
     break;

     case 'zh-TW':
        next_post_link( '%link', '下一個項目 ' . _x( '', 'next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' ); 
     break;

     case 'zh-CN':
        next_post_link( '%link', '下一个项目 ' . _x( '', 'next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' );
     break;

     default:
        next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Project ' . _x( '', 'next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' ); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an array as lookup table:

```
<?php 
    $languages = array(
        'es-ES' => array('next' => 'Proyecto Siguiente %s', 'prev' => '...'),
        //...
        'en' =>  array('next' => 'Next Project %s', 'prev' => '%s Previous Project')
    );

    $lang = get_bloginfo( 'language' ); 
    $lang = isset($languages[$lang]) ? $lang : 'en';
?>

<div id="next">
<?php next_post_link( '%link', sprintf($languages[$lang]['next'], _x( '', 'next post link', 'twentyten' ))); ?>
</div>

<div id="pref">
<?php previous_post_link( '%link', sprintf($languages[$lang]['prev'], _x( '', 'previous post link', 'twentyten' ))); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array.

```
$translations = array(
  'es-ES' => array(
    'next post' => 'Proyecto Siguiente %s',
     ...
  ),
  'zh-TW' => array(
     ...
  ),
   ...
  'default' => array(
    'next post' => 'Next Project %s',
     ...
  )
);

 ...

$language = 'default';
if (array_key_exists($translations, $current_language))
{
  $language = $current_language;
};

 ...

next_post_link('%link', sprintf($translations[$language]['next post'],
  _x( '', 'next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' ));
```

Doing this, you could also move the translations into a separate file and then build the array piece by piece from each.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter if that existsin php http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

```
(condition) ? true : false;
```

But for your issue you might want to consider an array of label. Here is an example

```
$currrentLanguage = 1;
$Label = new Array('NextProject' => New Array('New Project','Nouveau Projet', 'Blah blah'));

echo($Label ['NextProject'][$currrentLanguage])
```

In that case you will not have anymore if.